# Handling of Temporal Data

Tags: manipulate, random

I use a random function of a process which yields  a Temporal Data object,  I need but do not know how to recuperate  the numerical values of the process in a Table   from the Temporal Data.

Comment: Could you show us the code you've written so far? This will allow people to give you better answers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please insert the actual code in your question. Doing so will increase the chance of receiving good responses.

Answer (score 6):

#### Edit

`TemporalData` is one of those functions that accepts property names as arguments for extracting the information it holds. Please read the documentation for [`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) where will find a list of such properties and examples of their use.

Using example data taken from the documentation

```
s = {2, 1, 6, 5, 7, 4};
s2 = {22, 12, 62, 52, 72, 42};
t = {1, 2, 5, 10, 12, 15};
td = TemporalData[{s, s2}, {t}];
```

here are a couple of examples of extracting properties. This exacts the all the data.

```
td["Path", All]
```

> `{{{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {5, 6}, {10, 5}, {12, 7}, {15, 4}}, 
>   {{1, 22}, {2, 12}, {5, 62}, {10, 52}, {12, 72}, {15, 42}}}`

This extracts the first of the two sets of data values.

```
td["Values"]
```

> `{2, 1, 6, 5, 7, 4}`

This extracts the 2nd

```
td["Values", 2]
```

`{22, 12, 62, 52, 72, 42}`

This extracts both of them.

```
td["Values", All]
```

> `{{2, 1, 6, 5, 7, 4}, {22, 12, 62, 52, 72, 42}}`

This last may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Normal` to get the lists out of a [`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) object

> `Normal[td]` returns a list containing time-value pairs  for each path.

```
s = {2, 1, 6, 5, 7, 4};
s2 = {22, 12, 62, 52, 72, 42};
t = {1, 2, 5, 10, 12, 15};
td = TemporalData[{s, s2}, {t}];
Normal@td
(* {{{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {5, 6}, {10, 5}, {12, 7}, {15, 4}}, {{1, 
   22}, {2, 12}, {5, 62}, {10, 52}, {12, 72}, {15, 42}}} *)
```